# Geb 'at null' when asserting page

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I'm trying to write a simple Geb/Spock test using Grails but I am receiving the following test failure.

```
| Failure:  login works correctly(...UserAuthAcceptanceSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:

at HomePage
|
null
```

I can follow the test through with a debugger using a browser and can see that the application works as expected and the correct heading is being shown. However, the test is failing when I try to invoke the `at` checker. Can anyone tell me why the final assertion in the test might be failing and why the 'at' checker appears to be null?

Here is my code: (Geb v0.9.0, Grails 2.2.2)

**Spock Specification:**

```
class UserAuthAcceptanceSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "login works correctly"() {

        given: "the correct credentials"
            def theCorrectUsername = "admin"
            def theCorrectPassword = "password"

        when: "logging in"
            to LoginPage
            username = theCorrectUsername
            password = theCorrectPassword 
            submitButton.click() //([HomePage, LoginPage])

        then: "the welcome page is shown"
            heading =~ /(?i)Welcome.*/   // <- same as 'at' checker in HomePage
        and: "the 'at' checker works"
            at HomePage                  // <- fails

    }
```

**LoginPage**:

```
class LoginPage extends Page {

    final String path = "/login/auth"

    static content = {
        heading(required: false, wait:true) { $("h1").text() }
        username     { $("input", name:"j_username") }
        password     { $("input", name:"j_password") }
        submitButton { $("input", id:"submit") }
    }

    static at = {
        title =~ /Login.*/
    }

}
```

**HomePage**:

```
class HomePage extends Page {

    final String path   = "/"

    static content = {
        heading(required: false, wait:true) { $("h1").text() }
    }

    static at = {
        heading =~ /(?i)Welcome.*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `at` checker should use `==~` rather than `=~`.

Geb's implicit assertions mean the statements:

```
heading1 =~ /(?i)Welcome.*/
heading2 ==~ /(?i)Welcome.*/
```

effectively become:

```
assert (heading1 =~ /(?i)Welcome.*/) == true     // [1]      
assert (heading2 ==~ /(?i)Welcome.*/) == true    // [2]
```

[2] will evaluate to a boolean and pass/fail as expected, whereas [1] evaluates to a `java.util.regex.Matcher` causing the failure.

See the [Groovy Regex FAQ](http://groovy.codehaus.org/FAQ+-+RegExp) for an explanation of the difference between the two syntaxes.